# GET http://localhost/api/v1 404 nginx springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, nginx

I'm having a problem. I want to send a request to the nginx server so that it sends it to the spring boot server and returns it to me. But this error pops up:

[image]

The message "Hello" should be displayed on the screen, my controller is:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@Slf4j

public class PostsController {
    @GetMapping("/v1")
    public String helloWorld(){
        return "Hello";
    }

}
```

I got to this, since there were the same problems with the GRAPHQL API, the cross origin config in spring boot did not help. Help me please. I got to this, since there were the same problems with the GRAPHQL API, the cross origin config in spring boot did not help. Help me please, my nginx.conf is:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;


    location / {
      root     /var/www;
    }

    location /api/ {
      rewrite /api(.*) /$1  break;

      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }


    }
```

**UPDATE 1**
By typing in the url just localhost:8080/api/v1 the message is displayed: Hello

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want http://localhost/api/v1 to be passed to http://localhost:8080/api/v1 then your location needs to look like this:

```
location /api/ {

      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/api/;
```

Comment: Awesome dude, thanks. This saved my day after some hrs of debugging!